# Make Background an Image and views on top transparent

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Using SwiftUI for the first time, how do I make imageForBackground my background and everything else transparent?

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List(0..<5) { index in
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("\(index)")) {
                Image(systemName: "photo")
                VStack {
                    Text("\(index)")
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Hello World"), displayMode: .large)    
    }
    .padding()
    .frame(width: nil)
    .background(Image("imageForBackground"))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not show a background image using the List view, but using a different approach 
with a ScrollView and ForEach achieves what I think you want.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(0..<10, id: \.self) { index in
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("\(index)")) {
                        Image(systemName: "photo")
                        Text("\(index)")
                        Spacer()
                    }.padding(10)
                }
            }
        }.background(Image(systemName: "globe") // Image("imageForBackground")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .foregroundColor(.green))
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Hello World"), displayMode: .large)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI there is one specific modifier called opacity that can be used to change the alpha level of any colours and make it transparent.

for example in your image case

```
Image("myImage").opacity(0.8)
```

*More the 'opacty' value will be lower more the photo will be transparent.*

In your specific case

```
 .background(Image("imageForBackground").opacity(0.2))
```

You can use the same with the colours

```
Color(red: 1.0, green: 0, blue: 1.0, opacity: 0.2)
```

Hope I was helpful

Comment: This is not what I meant. The List and NavigationLink has the color of white. If I set them to ''' .background(Image("imageForBackground").opacity(0.2))''' then the same image would be set three times to different views (choppy). How can I make the List and NavigationLink background transparent so I can see 1 image throughout the view.